# How can i see which address Approved a WBNB spend for my address?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain, evm

I have been looking for a few hours in vain.

Let's say that a wallet wants to authorize the WBNB expense by approving on the WBNB contract the address of my wallet (approve function).

How can I know what is the exact address of this wallet that has approved? I am trying to identify the exact address via a TX.

Because in the transactions I don't see anything at all even if I try to filter.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can search `Approval` events by an address using node JSON-RPC API:

```
    /**
     * @dev Emitted when the allowance of a `spender` for an `owner` is set by
     * a call to {approve}. `value` is the new allowance.
     */
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
```

[More in IERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol).